# Use Postgres Function as ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have created a Postgres function that I am using in order to perform a complex query which joins many tables that all have to be filtered by a dynamic date field.

The function works perfectly, and allows my to perform a query like `"SELECT * FROM trail_for_date('2014-01-01')"` and returns a table.

A simplified example from the Postgres documentation on functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum_n_product_with_tab (x int)
RETURNS TABLE(sum int, product int) AS $$
    SELECT $1 + tab.y, $1 * tab.y FROM tab;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

How could I use this return table as a Rails/Ruby model where the argument to the function is dynamic?

Something like the following (which obviously doesn't work):

```
class SimplifiedExample < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'sum_n_product_with_tab(:dynamic_input)'
end
```

Comment: That's the original route that I went, but in my query I have to join about five tables that all filter on a single date and do computation based on that date... So I need to be able to pass in some kind of variable or use a function to accomplish this (I think).

Comment: I suppose I could, though its a 100+ line query, and I'd have to keep my query in sync with the database function the database guys have implemented.

Comment: Or you can use arel `Model.select(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('sum_n_product_with_tab', 6)).to_sql`

Answer (score 1):

Create a view containing the data you need and then you can easily create an ActiveRecord model to access it.

You haven't provided specific details of your data but as a simple example, create your view in Postgres to collect your data;

```
  create or replace view data_trails as
    select t.*, td.trail_date from trails t
    join trail_dates td on (td.trail_id = t.id)
```

Then create your model

```
  class DataTrail < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :on_date, -> (date) { where(trail_date: date) }
  end

  DataTrail.on_date(Date.today)
```

You can find more information in the Enterprise Rails book. It's getting a little dated now but the principles are sound.

http://enterpriserails.chak.org/full-text/chapter-11-view-backed-models

Comment: Views don't do it for me because the function needs the argument for a subquery inside the function. If I forgo the subquery and just filter after the function executes (as suggested here), then the function would be too slow as it will have to calculate for all rows of a table.

Answer (score 1):

create a dummy table with the same columns as your function output:

```
CREATE TABLE report.compliance_year (
year TIMESTAMP,
compliance NUMERIC(20,2),
fund_id INT);
```

Create your model:

```
class Visualization::ComplianceByYear < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'report.compliance_year'
    def compliance_by_year(fund_id)
        Visualization::ComplianceByYear.find_by_sql(["
            SELECT year, compliance, fund_id
              FROM report.usp_compliance_year(ARRAY[?])", fund_id])
    end
end
```

Reference it in your controller and populate it with the function call results:

```
def visualizations
  @compliancebyyear = Visualization::ComplianceByYear.new()
  @compliancefunds = @compliancebyyear.compliance_by_year(current_group.id)
end
```